# How to break "/home/username/ok/ok.txt" in a tree hierarchy in Python?

Tags: python, split

I get the output of the full path of the files or directories using this command in Python:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I get my output as in the question. Now I want to break my output as:

```
home
 username
   ok
     ok.txt
```

Tried using: `command.split('\')` but didn't work. After breaking I want to let user select the each file or directory too. How can I do that? Thanks

**Edit**:
Actually it is a list but I break it using join in Django Template so I guess it's a string now. Now output is like this:

```
django
django/genelaytics
django/genelaytics/.project
django/genelaytics/.pydevproject
django/genelaytics/manage.py
django/genelaytics/fileupload
django/genelaytics/fileupload/__init__.py
django/genelaytics/fileupload/__init__.pyc
django/genelaytics/fileupload/form.html~
django/genelaytics/fileupload/forms.py
django/genelaytics/fileupload/forms.pyc
django/genelaytics/fileupload/models.py
```

Desired output:

```
django
  genelaytics
    .project
     .pydevproject
```

I want tree structure of file and folder. Thanks

If converting to tree from string is hard I have this kind of list too:

```
['django', 'django/genelaytics', 'django/genelaytics/.project', 'django/genelaytics/.pydevproject', 'django/genelaytics/manage.py', 'django/genelaytics/fileupload', 'django/genelaytics/fileupload/__init__.py', 'django/genelaytics/fileupload/__init__.pyc']
```

I want the same output as above. If converting tree from string is easy, I will do that otherwise if converting tree from list is easy, let's do that whichever is easy. Not a problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will get you to 99% there ..

```
t = "/home/username/ok/ok.txt"
for i,j in enumerate(t.split("/")):
    print i * " " + j

 home
  username
   ok
    ok.txt
```

for python , string can be multiple by a number , like this :

```
"a" * 3
output: 'aaa'
```

and enumerate will return a tuple that first element is index of the iteratble object .

```
for i in enumerate(t.split("/")):
    print i


output: (0, '')
output: (1, 'home')
output: (2, 'username')
output: (3, 'ok')
output: (4, 'ok.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding, but assuming you have a string like that, would this work?

```
In [14]: s = '/home/username/ok/ok.txt'

In [15]: for index, el in enumerate(s.split('/')[1:]):
   ....:     print '  ' * index + el
   ....:
   ....:

  home
    username
      ok
        ok.txt
```

This iterates through the split string, skipping the first (blank) element and printing out the element prefaced by two spaces multiplied by the current index (0, 1, 2, etc.). Not sure what interface you want to use to allow choices, but I imagine you could do something like:

```
In [23]: for index, el in enumerate(s.split('/')[1:]):
   ....:     print '[{0}] {1}{2}'.format(index + 1, index * ' ', el)
   ....:
   ....:
[1] home
[2]  username
[3]   ok
[4]    ok.txt
```

This does essentially the same as above, adding in a 'marker' and using string formatting to display the string. To allow for a choice using `raw_input`, you could try something like:

```
In [26]: my_path = s.split('/')[1:]

In [27]: my_path
Out[27]: ['home', 'username', 'ok', 'ok.txt']

In [28]: choice = int(raw_input(('Enter choice: ')))
Enter choice: 2

In [29]: print my_path[choice-1]
username
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But, turns out this doesn't work with Django. Can you please edit your code to work in the template od Django? Thanks

Comment: @sachitad So you can pass the list to the template, but you need to know how to put it into the proper template syntax so that it displays as above? Just want to make sure I understand :)

Comment: Your approach is totally correct. But I have little problem. My list is like: ['home', 'home/zurelsoft', 'home/zurelsoft/R']. My desired output is:
home
 zurelsoft
   R
But I get mixed output following your approach:
home
  zurelsoft
    R
      home
        zurelsoft
          R
            R1
which is not what I wanted.

Comment: If I can sort out this with your help, I will mark your answer best answer :)

Comment: @sachitad Ah, so it's not a string, it's a list? Will it always be the case that the final element is the one you want to parse? Or are you trying to perform the above action for every element in the list?

Comment: @sachitad Is your example above just a shortened example of what you want? Or do you only want those four levels?

Comment: That's the example of what I want. I want all the level there exist. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`os.path.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path#os.path.split).